Does China have any sanctions on Hezbollah, or do they at least implicitly obey some US sanctions in that regard?
I'm slightly curious why Hezbollah bought the famous pagers apparently from Taiwan. (The Taiwanese firm is actually denying that they made them now, saying they were actually made by a mysterious licensor of the brand--possibly based in Europe--reportedly Budapest, Hungary.) Nonetheless, you'd think Hezbollah would be more wary of electronics that advertise themselves as made by West-allied countries, especially communications equipment.
Does China itself have some sanctions (official or unofficial) on Hezbollah? Or at least, do many Chinese companies follow the US sanctions in that area, and so refuse to sell to Hezbollah?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I am not sure how solid this question is.  What makes you think that Hezbollah had to identify itself as "International terrorist organization of mystery" on the purchase of a large quantity of civilian electronics?  These aren't weapons and they don't require any end user certificates.  They could have said they were a government department, a trucking firm, etc...   A pager vendor probably welcomed the biz. The Ukraine war has complicated things a bit on electronic components, but sanctions are widely evaded via shipments to third party countries.
